# Is there any Validator in TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class EmailITextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final IconData icon;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final Validator validator; //here
  const EmailITextField({
    Key key,
    this.hintText,
    this.icon = Icons.person,
    this.onChanged,
    this.validator,
    this.controller
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFieldContainer(
      child: TextFormField(
        validator: validator,
        controller: controller,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        cursorColor: kPrimaryightColor,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(
            icon,
            color: kPrimaryColor,
          ),
          labelText: hintText,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor) ,
          hintText: "example@email.com",
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There is no Validator thing, i want to add Validator attribute on this reusable widget, but i dont know how to add the Validator attribute.
any other name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EmailTextField(
  validator: (String value) {
              if (value.trim().isEmpty){ 
                return 'Email cannot be empty.';
              }
              return null;
  },
)
```

Like this, you can create more if statements to validate the inputted value
you can also reference a method here like,

```
EmailTextField(validator: _validate);



String _validate() {
  if (value.trim().isEmpty){ 
  return 'Email cannot be empty.';
  }
  return null;

}
```

Forgive me if there is any syntax error

Answer (score 1):

There is and this is how you do it:

```
TextFormField(
  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  },
);
```

If the validator returns `null` that means the validation passed else it will show the string as error which was return from the `validator` method. Bonus point, if your `TextFormField` is inside a `Form` then when the form's `validate()` method is called, this validator will automatically called.

Check out the [official document here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation).